# How can I allow a player to develop his PC's own unique fighting style?

Tags: star-wars-age-of-rebellion

My current group is very eager to start a new campaign in the pirates-with-superpowers [*One Piece*](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Piece) setting. As such, it's important that everyone come up with abilities or fighting styles, sometimes on the fly. My players are a very creative bunch and enjoy this kind of stuff (and they don't abuse the privilege).

Do rules for something like this exist for the [*Age of Rebellion*](https://www.fantasyflightgames.com/en/products/star-wars-age-of-rebellion/) system or its associated games? Alternatively, is there a playtested homebrew ruleset that meets my needs?

Comment: Age of Rebellion isn't a great match for a superpowers game, which One Piece pretty much has to be (unless nobody has a devil fruit, at which point you are losing a lot of the One Piece flavor)  There are definitely superpowers systems that would work better, but I wouldn't want to recommend one without having played any of them.

Comment: The site no longer supports game recommendations, so I edited that out of your question to narrow its focus. Feel free to rollback or edit further to make the question ask what you want.

Comment: @HeyICanChan, nah I prefer your edited version anyways. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up developing a way to 'craft' fighting skills.
The players get a certain amount of points after each session that can be spend to craft fighting skills using the following pattern:

1. Name of the fighting skill
2. Main attribute of the fighting skill (e.g strength)
3. How much damage and what kind of damage the skill should do
4. (Optional) If the skill should apply status effects to the enemy or PC
5. (Optional) Adding costs to the skill in order to decrease the crafting cost (e.g material cost, can only be used once per session, needs the enemy to be stunned etc.)

This assures that everyone can have the kind of abilities they want to have, but at the same time everything is balanced.

Of course this is far from perfect, especially because I have the feeling that it is somewhat **too** balanced. But the players love it.

Hope this ends up helping someone.